# How can I filter data into tables when clicking on a collection cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, filter, uicollectionviewcell

I have a horizontal collection and a table with data, how can I change the data in the table when clicking on a collection cell?

The result I want to get is shown in the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Implement `didSelectItemAt` and filter the data accordingly.

Comment: Would you be able to send an example of the code